# Recognize numbers on a string (SHELL)

Tags: shell

I am trying to do an algorithm that recognize numbers on a String and put that numbers on a variable.
For example "abc 123" save 123 on a variable.
Thanks.

Comment: what would you try to save if the string is `foo 0 abc 123 foo 456`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

since a string could have  more number segments, so I would go with sed:

```
sed 's/[^0-9]//g'

kent$  echo "foo 0 abc 123 foo 456"|sed 's/[^0-9]//g' 
0123456
```

I hope this is what you want.

oh, forgot the "saving to variable" part:

```
kent$  number=$(echo "foo 0 abc 123 foo 456"|sed 's/[^0-9]//g')


kent$  echo $number
0123456
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you need only the first number:

```
myNumber="$(printf %s "$myString" | grep -Eo '[[:digit:]]+' | head -1)"
```

Comment: Is there a reason to use printf "%s" "$myString" instead of echo "$myString" ?

Comment: Yes, it is the safest way to echo a string literally. For example, if your string is "-n", then many echo versions wouldn't work.